# Pandas: conditional lookup based on a dynamic value (column) in two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes in the following format

```
DF1:
    YearNb  MonthNb  WeekNb NatCoCode      BNCode  LocalPrice
0     2017        7      27       OBE  BN20008222          60
1     2017        7      28       OBE  BN20008222          61
2     2017        7      29       OBE  BN20008222          62
3     2017        7      30       OBE  BN20008223          63
4     2017        8      31       OBE  BN20008223          64
5     2017        8      32       OBE  BN20008223          65
6     2017        8      33       OBE  BN20008223          66
7     2017        7      27       OFR  BN20008222          67
8     2017        7      28       OFR  BN20008222          68
9     2017        7      29       OFR  BN20008222          69
10    2017        7      30       OFR  BN20008223          70
11    2017        8      31       OFR  BN20008223          71
12    2017        8      32       OFR  BN20008223          72

DF2:
    YearNb_x  MonthNb_x  WeekNb_x NatCoCode VariantCode
0       2017          7        27       OBE  BN20008222
1       2017          7        28       OBE  BN20008222
2       2017          9        34       OBE  BN20008223
3       2018          4        18       OBE  BN20008222
4       2017          8        31       OBE  BN20008222
5       2017          8        32       OBE  BN20008222
6       2018          7        27       OFR  BN20008222
7       2017          7        28       OFR  BN20008223
8       2017          7        29       OFR  BN20008222
9       2017          8        31       OFR  BN20008222
10      2017          8        32       OFR  BN20008223
```

What I am trying to do is to fetch the **latest** prices available in DF2 and add it to a new column (LocalPrice) in DF1. The frequency of this data is weekly, week number is based on calendar week (1 to last week in the year), the BNCode (same as VariantCode) is a unique ID for a product, the condition is:

IF there is a price for the same code, same week, same year, I want this price.

OTHERWISE I would take the latest available (week before, two weeks ago, three, and so on...)

Here is what I tried to do, but to be honest I am not really familiar with pandas in this level, so I guess my logic is not correct:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('test1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('test2.xlsx')

def PriceAssignment(df1,df2):
    # condition = add local price for item based on BNCode, Year, Month and Week, 
    #IF there is no price for current week, take the week before and so on, until a price is found (Latest)
    for i in df1['VariantCode'], df2['BNCode']:
        if df1.loc[df1[i], df1['YearNb_x'], df1['WeekNb_x'], df1['NatCoCode'], df1['VariantCode']] == df2.loc[df2[i], df2['YearNb_x'], df2['WeekNb_x'], df2['NatCoCode'], df2['VariantCode']]:
            df1['LocalPrice'] == df2.loc['Price']
        elif df2['WeekNb']==1:
            df2['YearNb'] -= 1
    return df1
```

This is just a small sample, I have a much larger dataset, the idea again is to take either the price for the same week number, in case it exists, otherwise take the one for the latest week in the past. If none of the criteria is valid, it could just be empty, future prices (for weeks after the one in DF2) are not interesting. I manually drafted the possible outcome, it would be something like this:

```
    YearNb_x  MonthNb_x  WeekNb_x NatCoCode VariantCode  Price
0       2017          7        27       OBE  BN20008222     60
1       2017          7        28       OBE  BN20008222     61
2       2017          9        34       OBE  BN20008223     66
3       2018          4        18       OBE  BN20008222     63
4       2017          8        31       OBE  BN20008222     63
5       2017          8        32       OBE  BN20008222     63
6       2018          7        27       OFR  BN20008222     67
7       2017          7        28       OFR  BN20008223  empty
8       2017          7        29       OFR  BN20008222     69
9       2017          8        31       OFR  BN20008222     70
10      2017          8        32       OFR  BN20008223     72
```

Does anyone have a better suggestion on how I can handle this? I have also tried merging the data frames but i didnt succeed as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: i think your question would get more attention if you added the expected output, & removed columns from `df1` & `df2` that are not involved in this join.

Comment: @HaleemurAli, thank you very much and I apologize for my sloppiness. I believe it looks better now. Is it clear now?

Comment: @jpp, thank you very much for the support, I tried to make it clear as possible :)

Comment: Looked like you need [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof), but it's complicated by the fact you also want to merge by multiple other columns. A workaround is to iterate items of `groupby([grouper_columns])`, perform a `merge_asof` for each group, then concatenate results. Messy IMO, hopefully someone can see a better solution.

Comment: @jpp maybe merging would work if it creates an entry for every item in DF1 with the LocalPrice in DF2, then I could delete the rows without Volume or Price from the other DF (NaN). I am actually trying to do that but it Im not sure if Im doing correctly. You think this would be a possible solution or should I stop trying with this thinking?